# Split Multiple Options in Single Attribute in Magento

Tags: php, string, magento, attributes, explode

I have multiple options in an attributes in Magento and when I call the attribute, all of the options show in a string and I would like to show them on separate lines (p tags or li's).

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('spamodel') ?>
```

The above is my code, I think i need to use explode but I'm a newbie at php.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you post your content which you want to explode..

Comment: Miami, Vegas, Saint Tropez, Palm Springs, Paris, Hawaii, Siena, Monaco, Havana, New York

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $spamodel = $this->getChildHtml('spamodel'); 
      $spamodel_explode = explode(",",$spamodel);
      echo $spamodel_explode[0];
?>
```

Here you can go with this code. you can get single the names with `$spamodel_explode[0]` and if you want to get all the names than you can use **forloop**

Answer (score 1):

Here You can able to get the answer

```
<?php 
      $variable = $this->getChildHtml('spamodel')
      $variable_exp = explode(",",$variable)
      foreach($variable_exp as $var){
         echo $var;
      }    
?>
```

In above coding you can explode based on your requirement.Just replace the ',' tag and get the results based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below link for more details.

http://www.brandammo.co.uk/output-magento-custom-attributes-to-front-end-from-multi-select-dropdowns/

Comment: Cheers for the answer but I didn't really get on with that solution